# Recursive method not reaching the base case, however, I'm not sure why. Java

Tags: java, recursion, case, radix

This is kind of a weird project, so bare with the pretty weird code. The real issue I'm having is why exactly this recursive method is never reaching the base case.

```
public int determinant() {
    int determinant = 0;
    if(getSize() == 2)
    {
        return (getElement(1, 1) * getElement (2, 2)) - (getElement(1,2) * getElement(2,1));
    }

    determinant += Math.pow(-1, getSize()+1) * getElement(getSize(), 1) * minor(getSize(),1).determinant();
    return determinant;
}

public SparseInterface minor(int row, int col) {
    SparseMatrix minor = new SparseMatrix();
    minor.matrix = matrix;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
    {
        if(row == minor.matrix.get(i).getRow() || col == minor.matrix.get(i).getCol())
        {
            minor.matrix.remove(i);
        }
    }
    minor.size--;
    return minor;
}
```

So, determinant calls minor, which returns a new square matrix that's size is 1 smaller. I start with a 5x5 matrix, and I call the determinant method on it. That method then takes the determinant of the minor of the 5x5 matrix (a 4x4 matrix). This goes on until we reach the base case, where it is a 2x2 matrix and calculating the determinant is trivial.

However, the issue lies in the fact that the code never gets past the point of it being a 4x4 matrix. Every time that minor gets called (which it should on every recursive call) it should put out smaller matrix, due to the last line of code in minor, minor.size--;.

With some bug testing, it seems that the size of the matrix gets decremented the first time, but not on subsequent recursive calls. I'm somewhat new to Java, does Java have some weird rules in regards to method calls within method calls that is causing it to not get decremented the way it should be? Other than that I am at a loss.

Thanks in advance.

For those who asked:

```
public int getElement(int row, int col) {
    int element = 0;
    if(row > getSize() || col > getSize())
    {
        System.out.println("Column/row combination is out of bounds.");
        return element;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
    {
        if(matrix.get(i).getRow() == row && matrix.get(i).getCol() == col)
        {
            element = matrix.get(i).getData();
        }
    }
    return element;
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}
```

Size is is just a data member of the class SparseMatrix, that says the weird nonexistent matrix I'm modeling is SizexSize. For more details I wrote about it in the comments below.

```
public class SparseMatrix implements SparseInterface {
public LinkedList<Index> matrix;
public int size;

public SparseMatrix() {
    matrix = new LinkedList<Index>();
    size = 5;

}
```

Comment: Please show us the code for `getElement()` and `getSize()`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen minor does not call minor, but determinant calls determinant.

Comment: @AidanO'Connell Yeah, you're right. Missed that.

Comment: Yeah, there's no recursive stuff happening as far as I can tell. You're also newing up SparseMatrix at the beginning of the method before the decrement every time. So your minor.size-- will do the same thing every time, unless you're creating SparseMatrix as a singleton in a weird constructor way, which I don't think is possible, or size is static final or something.  I think we need to see a lot more code to know exactly what is happening, but recursion isn't happening in this code.

Comment: wait - determinant calls determinant.  I would suggest renaming your variables to not be the exact same as your methods.  It's confusing and less readable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is an odd school project. It's one of those ones where in the real world theres a library that makes this easy, but its about learning so they make us do it without the use of a library. basically they want us to model a sparse matrix without having any of the 0s committed to memory, so i have a linked list of index objects that contain the row col and data of non zero entries

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I will add those methods to the original post though

Comment: Can you provide the code for your other classes? Specifically the SparseMatrix class?

Comment: @adpro 
I'll add to original post

Comment: Your issue is that you're newing it up and size always starts at 5 for you.  It decrements once, then your method is called, the SparseMatrix is newed up again, size is set to 5 again, because you just newed it up, and then decrements to 4 again.

Comment: @adpro That makes sense, thank you so much.

Comment: You either have to instantiate the SparseMatrix object in this class elsewhere as a class wide object to keep its state (the size value) or do this in some other way. When you leave that method the SparseMatrix object goes out of scope and is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

The code is a bit confusing to me.  I think you're trying to keep the state of the **SparseMatrix** object in the `minor()` method.

I think something like this is what you would be looking for maybe?

The `minor.determinant()` is a tad bit confusing.  Is there a different `determinant()` method in **SparseMatrix**?  You were previously returning the **SparseMatrix** object created in the minor method, and previously had `minor(getSize(),1).determinant()`.  It looks like you're calling the `determinant()` method inside the **SparseMatrix** class, but I don't see that method in that class in your code.  Are these methods all in the **SparseMatrix** class?

I would also suggest changing the variable names of your objects to something different than the method names you are using.  It reduces readability of your code.

Either way, I think this can get you going.

```
private SparseMatrix minor = new SparseMatrix();

public int determinant() {
    int determinant = 0;

    if(getSize() == 2)
    {
        return (getElement(1, 1) * getElement (2, 2)) - (getElement(1,2) * getElement(2,1));
    }

    minor(getSize(),1);

    determinant += Math.pow(-1, getSize()+1) * getElement(getSize(), 1) * this.minor.determinant();

    return determinant;
}

public void minor(int row, int col) {
    //in your previous code, I'm not sure where you're getting Matrix from, 
    //so I'll leave this in here - I think you're also wanting to use the 
    //matrix that is now stored in your minor object, so I changed that in
    //the for loop, but there are likely more elegant solutions for this if
    //I saw all the code
    minor.matrix = matrix;

    for(int i = 0; i < this.minor.matrix.size(); i++)
    {
        if(row == this.minor.matrix.get(i).getRow() || col == this.minor.matrix.get(i).getCol())
        {
            this.minor.matrix.remove(i);
        }
    }

    this.minor.size--;
}
```